# Using hooks with Apollo Provider

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, apollo, react-apollo, react-apollo-hooks

Here is a Codesandbox link recreating the issue:
https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-nash-svcj7?file=/src/index.js

I'm having a weird issue. I have a very simple setup Apollo setup just for testing purposes. It goes like this:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <Main />
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
}
```

It's just a simple ApolloProvider that provides the client to the App component. The App component just has one line.

```
const Main = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  setData(1);
  return <div>Test</div>;
};
```

Now, when I refresh my page, I get this error:

```
Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
```

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Why can't I use a simple hook inside of my component?

Here is the full code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import ApolloClient from "apollo-client";
import { InMemoryCache } from "apollo-cache-inmemory";
import { HttpLink } from "apollo-link-http";
import { ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/react-hooks";

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: new HttpLink({
    uri: "https://api.graph.cool/simple/v1/swapi"
  }),
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});

const Main = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  setData(1);
  return <div>Test</div>;
};

function App() {
  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <Main />
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

There is an example I was following where it *does* work, so I'm not sure why my example isn't.

https://codesandbox.io/s/replace-previous-results-with-next-results-nuu6x?file=/src/FilmTitles.jsx:16-24

Comment: where is `setCursor ` come from?

Comment: oops, i meant setData

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you cannot `setState` in `render` function of the component. And for functional components their body is the `render` function. In this case `setData` updates the state which triggers re-rendering and on each render it calls `setData` again in the infinite loop:

```
function App() {
    const [data, setData] = useState(0);
    setData(1); // this triggers re-render which is execution of App() which again calls setData(1)
}
```

Comment: It's not true. Yes, we should NEVER call `setState ` in body of functional component. But it's not the reason this case. When you call `setState` React will check if the state is really changed, if yes it re-render, if no it don't. `data` is number, so it only re-render once when data change from `0` to `1`, when `data` is `1` and  you call `setData(1)` React will not re-render the component.

Comment: You are wrong @TonyNguyen Here is the quote from the official docs
**setState() will always lead to a re-render unless shouldComponentUpdate() returns false.**
and the [reference to it](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

Comment: yes, but it is working on this example, so why? https://codesandbox.io/s/replace-previous-results-with-next-results-nuu6x?file=/src/FilmTitles.jsx:16-24

Comment: @a53-416 because `setSkip` is called in a callback for `onClick` event and it is ok

Comment: Ah, now i see where i may be going wrong. thank you

Comment: @Rostyslav the quote you mentioned is for class component, in functional component there is no `shouldComponentUpdate `. For functional component **If your update function returns the exact same value as the current state, the subsequent rerender will be skipped completely.** refered from here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates

Comment: @TonyNguyen just checkout this sandbox and see the error

https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-mclaren-fck29?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I checked the codesandbox and saw `setState` cause the probem, but your explaination is not true.

Comment: @TonyNguyen so what is your expanation? :) if my explanation is wrong just convince me with yours...

Comment: You can check out the link from official documents that I mentioned, I don't have answer for now.

Comment: You can also put the `setData(1)` inside a useEffect WITHOUT dependency, why it does not get infinite re-render? (based on your explanation it should be re-rendered infinitely)

Comment: @TonyNguyen I have checked the link and there is a statement:
***If you update a State Hook to the same value as the current state, React will bail out without rendering the children or firing effects. Note that React may still need to render that specific component again before bailing out*** so it seems that it does render...

Comment: Thanks @Rostyslav. Now it make all sense.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to setState like that, at this moment if you just want to try put `setData` in a `useEffect` and you don't get this error again

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setData(1);
  }, [data]);
```